# NGINX - Rewrite fancy url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I thought rewrite in Nginx would be straight-forward. It looks like its not.

I would like some help from you guys. My previous setup was Apache2 + PHP. My new setup is Nginx + PHP-FPM.

I would like to transform a simple virtualhost from Apache2.

The directory structure is:

- /api (this is root)

  - VERSION (1)

    --- api.php

    --- .htaccess

Fx. domain.tld/1/

The .htaccess files looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/api.json$ api.php?app=$1&sapp=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/api.json$ api.php?app=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My new Nginx server file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/domain.tld/api;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name domain.tld;

        location /1/ {
                rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/api\.json$ /api.php?app=$1&sapp=$2;
                rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/api\.json$ /api.php?app=$1;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include php5;
        }
}
```

But it does not works when I try to view: domain.tld/1/view/api.json or domain.tld/1/view/extended/api.json

Can anyone explain and give some examples to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how NGiNX processes `location` blocks, here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

As you can see in your case the request is only served by your `location /1/` block, as that is the only one of the two that matches. Problem is, NGiNX only uses one location block per request, so once it got into the `location /1/` block, it will not go to the other location block later. 
The solution here is to also include your `php5` file in the `location /1/` block at the end.

```
location /1/ {
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/api\.json$ /api.php?app=$1&sapp=$2;
    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)/api\.json$ /api.php?app=$1;
    include php5;
}
```